# Rich text is not showing in SXA toolbox

Tags: sxa, components

We have an issue in rich text component in Sitecore SXA, it is not showing in the SXA toolbox.

I have checked under Presentation > Available rendering > Page Content it is showing under rendering field.

Could someone assist me what is the issue and what can we check in Sitecore except the approach I have checked ?

Comment: Do you have a placeholder on the page that allows the RT component? (check the placeholder settings)

Comment: I have checked placeholder setting  and richtext field is there. I have checked under layout/placeholder setting / feature / Experience accelerator / page content / richtext there. Am I checking the correct path ?

Comment: No, in SXA you need to set the placeholders per site. You can find them in the Presentation folder of your site.

Comment: In that placeholder setting I don't have anything. It is empty

Answer (score -1):

Please add Richtext rendering on below mentioned Sitecore path (Data Section - Renderings Fields)

```
/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Presentation/Available Renderings/Page Content
```

Comment: I think she has already mentioned in the question that the rendering exists on this path.